# Unable to set the value into Label dynamically

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a label as shown

```
<label id="label1"></label>
```

I am trying to set the value in it using

```
document.getElementById('label1').text = "ddd";
```

And i also i tried using Prototype as

```
$('label1').text = date1;
```

But still its not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("label1").innerText = "foobar"
```

or alternatively

```
document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML = "<b>fatfoo</b>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following

`$('#label1').text(date1);`

text is a method here.

Answer (score 0):

Use the innerText or innerHTML property:

```
document.getElementById("label1").innerText="ddd";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try .innerHTML, innerText, .textContent, .nodeValue

I have only seen .text in selects

(I need to stop commenting and answer instead...)

Answer (score 0):

A label element is supposed to enclose a form control, e.g.

```
<label id="label1" for="firstName">First name:
  <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName"></label>
```

If that is how you are using it, then you don't want to replace it's *[innerHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/apis-in-html-documents.html#innerhtml)*, *[innerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533899%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)* or *[textContent](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent)* as doing so will completely replace the content of the label (removing any elements within it). If you aren't using the label this way, you should be using some other element, probably a span.

While *innerHTML* is widely supported, it's only been standardised in HTML5, which is still a draft. However, you can usually assume support and setting it is pretty consistent across browsers. Getting the property has foibles and isn't very consistent if it's anything other than trivial markup (e.g. text and simple inline elements).

The *innerText* property is a Microsoft proprietary property that is supported by IE and some other browsers, it definitely **should not** be used without feature testing. Similarly, the W3C DOM 3 *textContent* property is not widely supported, but is generally supported by those browsers that don't support *innerText* (some support both).

It's pretty easy to do a feature test and select which one to use, such as:

```
if (typeof element.textContent == 'string') {
  // use textContent property

} else if (typeof element.innerText == 'string') {
  // use innerText property
}
```

where *element* is a reference to a DOM element node.

It's probably best to wrap the text you want to replace in a span element and replace the content of that, either using *innerHTML* or, if it contains a single text node, its `firstChild.data`.

Comment: Since when do you need to wrap a form control in a label??? Please show me the documentation for that. NOT [here at MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/label) nor at [w3org ' 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1), not [w3org html5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) where you CAN but do not HAVE to put the control inside
Also innerText is now supported in most modern browsers. innerHTML is supported in ALL browsers since the beginning of this millennium

Comment: @mplungjan - I didn't say form controls *must* be wrapped in a label, but that that is the *purpose* of label elements. Read the spec you linked to: `The LABEL element may be used to attach information to controls`. *innerText* is not supported by Gecko based browsers, it is not a standard, hence the recommendation it be feature tested. I didn't say browsers don't support *innerHTML*, but that **reading** the property gives different results in different browsers for non-trivial content. I recommended it for setting the content.

Comment: I do not see that as the purpose and do not read that anywhere I looked. The label attribute _for_ is created for when the label is not wrapping the field. Sorry about the innerText, I just saw it recently used and believed it worked in Fx too. However in my answer I did add the textContent too.

Comment: @mplungjan - don't take my word for it in regard to labels, ask in an HTML forum. Their purpose is for form controls, the element really has no other use that isn't already fulfilled by a span. In IE (less than about 8 anyway), the *for* attribute is necessary to associate the label with the control, even when it wraps it.

Comment: the innerText I saw last was in Chrome. I use the label for="formelemntId" in all browsers to allow clicking the label to focus or select the element - that is the only purpose of the pabel tag, to have the text clickable . I NEVER wrap the label around the form element. To use a span as label is not interesting since it will not automatically focus or select/check the element it is next to.

Comment: @mplungjan - please read the spec you linked to: `The LABEL element is used to specify labels for controls that do not have implicit labels`. Primarily they are for radio buttons and checkboxes. Also, I said they should be used with form *controls*, not form *elements* (which would be invalid markup). I didn't say span elements are always an alternative, but that labels have one special purpose (as a label or caption for form controls that don't have intrinsic labels or captions) and that **other than that**, a span or div can be used. None of your criticisms has any basis in fact.

Comment: What can I say. My criticism was based on the extraordinary length you went to dissuade the asker from changing the innerHTML of the label and move the form element or control or whatever you want to name it, inside the label and do feature testing and so on. Incredible overkill. Let's just agree to disagree.